# Could a Pokemon be helpful to human(s) without being captured?

Tags: pokemon

Looking at the lore of the manga, movies, TV series, video games of Pokemon, is it unreasonable to assume that an uncaptured Pokemon would always be hostile to a human, simply by the fact that they are human, even if they've never seen one before (an undiscovered island or something)? Also, would an uncaptured Pokemon actually be helpful to a human who's in some sort of a dire circumstance (for instance, stopping someone falling to their death at the edge of a cliff, or guiding someone who's lost without supplies back to civilization)?

Comment: Definitely because Legendaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at the lore of the manga, movies, TV series, video games of Pokemon, is it unreasonable to assume that an uncaptured Pokemon would always be hostile....

There is no correlation between a captured Pokemon and hostility, as there are examples shown where captured pokemon would NOT listen to their master.

Examples:

in the first Pokemon, Charizard would not listen to Ash at first, even though Charmander was saved by Ash and was a good "friend."

Also in the Original Pokemon, Garados would not listen to "Team Rocket" and do it's own thing.

There are also examples of non-captured Pokemon being friendly.

In the original Pokemon Pikachu was never inside a Pokeball, but was faithful to Ash throughout the entire series.

Also in the original Pokemon, Meowth, from "Team Rocket" was never inside a pokeball, as well as Giovanni having a Persian form sitting beside him as a trophy cat.

> ... to a human, simply by the fact that they are human, even if they've never seen one before (an undiscovered island or something)?

I would assume being a human has nothing to do with hostility, like in the real world, some animals are hostile, some aren't.

> Also, would an uncaptured Pokemon actually be helpful to a human who's in some sort of a dire circumstance (for instance, someone who's about to fall to their death at the edge of a cliff, or someone who's lost without supplies and guiding them back to civilization)?

There have been instances of pokemon doing good things.  I believe in the original pokemon, the "Squritle Squad" ended up coming back to help Ash, and then the leader joined up with Ash on his own accord, and accepted life inside the pokeball.

The thing about Ash, is that he could have had most of his pokemon outside of Pokeballs, but it would have been too much.

Pikachu REFUSED to get inside a pokeball though.

Comment: But that brings up the question as to why by and far most are hostile, and the few that are doing good/ helpful things are so rare. If Pokemon are a direct analogue to IRL animals, most animals are outright scared of humans, and will flee, unless cornered.

Comment: From a few points above, you can see that Evolved Pokemon tend to more hostile, due to strength, but strength isn't the only factor.  Mew is/was one of the strongest pokemon, yet it was childishly unhostile, compared to the crazy hostile Mewtwo, which could be seen from "Pokemon The Movie."  In our world it all depends on what kind of animal it is.  Some are hostile by nature, some aren't.  Size has nothing to do with it either. Some small animals are deadlier than their larger counterparts, and some large animals are calm.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. And in the manga/ video games/ tv series/ movies you (or the characters) don't see the ones that flee, only the ones that confront you and you're / they're forced (or choose) to fight.

Comment: There are many instances where you see scared pokemon that are trying to hide, or avoid being detected, or just hanging out.  Slowbro/poke in the original Pokemon just chilled..  Psyduck really didn't do much either, and just stood around.  There are some insect pokemon that are cacoons and just chill in trees trying to hide and blend in.  There was also a game for the N64 called "Pokemon Snap" where you had to take pictures of pokemon and the entire game had pokemon that were out and about, some hiding and being scared, but most of the time just doing their thing.

Comment: I had forgotten about those side games that aren't the explore and capture. Also (and I'm adding something to your answer) the Pokemon Dungeon games are the titular characters are doing good as well.

Comment: Pokemon has evolved into something amazing, but it's hard to say what is canon or not, and if games such as `Pokemon Snap` are questioned since it's goal is to take pictures.  The thing is, as mentioned, a lot of them try to hide or get past you quickly, so it shows the world as if you were there.  Even without games, the Original show has all the proof needed.  I would assume other shows would follow suit.